# Return a value if there is an unidentified operator javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a code that recognizes operators in an array and use the to form calculations based on another array. Below is the code

```js
function interpret(...args) {
  let operators = args[1]; //get the operators array
  let values = args[2] //numbers expect the first one.
  return values.reduce((ac, val, i) => {
    //check the operator at the 'i' on which we are on while iterating through 'value'
    if (operators[i] === '+') return ac + val;
    if (operators[i] === '-') return ac - val;
    if (operators[i] === '*') return ac * val;
    if (operators[i] === '/') return ac / val;
    else return -1;
  }, args[0]) //'ac' is initially set to first value.
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1]))
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2]))
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '$', '+'], [5, 3, 2])) //It fails in this case and gives 1
```

Kindly help with fixing this issue. Thanks

Comment: The first arguments contains the operators performing the calculations

Comment: Yea but i want this solution to work

Comment: Yea very correct

Comment: what is the expected result for the last one ? because it should return `1`, it's not failing

Comment: All operators.But should return -1 if there is an unrecognized operator. The above example would be `(1 + 1) * 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag such as `invalid`, so that your reduce function only returns `-1` if it finds an invalid operator:

```js
function interpret(...args) {
  let operators = args[1]; //get the operators array
  let invalid = false; // no invalid operators
  let values = args[2] //numbers expect the first one.
  return values.reduce((ac, val, i) => {
    //check the operator at the 'i' on which we are on while iterating through 'value'
    if (!invalid) { // if invalid is false then:
      if (operators[i] === '+') return ac + val;
      if (operators[i] === '-') return ac - val;
      if (operators[i] === '*') return ac * val;
      if (operators[i] === '/') return ac / val;
    }
    // If invalid is true or the above operators did not match, then
    invalid = true; // this will only be set to true if the above if statments didn't run
    return -1 // return -1 (this will always be executred from now on as the if(!invalid) will not run the code within it anymore

  }, args[0]) //'ac' is initially set to first value.
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1]))
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2]))
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '$', '+'], [5, 3, 2])) // -1
```

Or, you could use a new approach to achieve this such as a recursive solution:

```js
const oper = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b
};

const interpret = (n, [fc, ...calcs], [fn, ...nums]) => {
  if(fc === undefined) return n;
  if(!(fc in oper)) return -1;
  return interpret(oper[fc](n, fn), calcs, nums)
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1]))
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2]))
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '$', '+'], [5, 3, 2])) // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing all the possible operations in an map of `operator => function`, like:

```
const operations = {
  "+": function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  "-": function(a, b) { return a - b; },
  "*": function(a, b) { return a * b; },
  "/": function(a, b) { return a / b; }
};
```

Then you can just get that operation and if it doesn't exist return `NaN` to convert the final result to `NaN`. At the end end just check if the result is `NaN` and return `-1` if it is. Also I wouldn't recommend using `arguments` if you can just declare the variables.

```js
const operations = {
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "-": (a, b) => a - b,
  "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  "/": (a, b) => a / b
};

function empty() { return NaN; }

function numberOrDefault(res, def) { return isNaN(res) ? def : res; }

function interpret(start, operators, values) {
  return numberOrDefault(values.reduce((acc, val, i) => (operations[operators[i]] || empty)(acc, val), start), -1);
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1]));
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2]));
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]));
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]));
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '$', '+'], [5, 3, 2]));
```

If you don't want to change anything here is a solution with the least possible changes:

```js
function interpret(...args) {
  let operators = args[1]; //get the operators array
  let values = args[2] //numbers expect the first one.
  let result = values.reduce((ac, val, i) => {
    //check the operator at the 'i' on which we are on while iterating through 'value'
    if (operators[i] === '+') return ac + val;
    if (operators[i] === '-') return ac - val;
    if (operators[i] === '*') return ac * val;
    if (operators[i] === '/') return ac / val;
    else return NaN;
  }, args[0]); //'ac' is initially set to first value.
  return isNaN(result) ? -1 : result;
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1]))
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2]))
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '$', '+'], [5, 3, 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually add a "parsing" phase before the interpretation, were I would scan both the operations and the values validating the sanity of the given input
To avoid any possible surprise, I would enclose the actual interpretation in a try/catch.

I also really like the nick's solution so I'm gonna take some inspiration from it.

```js
const oper = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b
};
const opers = Object.keys(oper)

function interpret(...args) {
  let operators = args[1];
  let values = args[2]

  const validOperators = operators.every(op => opers.includes(op) )
  const validValues = values.every(val => typeof val === "number" )

  if(!validOperators || !validValues)
    return -1

  try {
    return values.reduce((ac, val, i) => {
        const curOper = operators[i]
        return oper[curOper](ac, val)
      }, args[0])
  } catch(e){
    return -1
  }
}

console.log(interpret(1, ["+"], [1]))
console.log(interpret(4, ["-"], [2]))
console.log(interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(5, ["+", "*", "-"], [4, 1, 3]))
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '$', '+'], [5, 3, 2]))
console.log(interpret(10, ['*', '*', '+'], [5, 3, "dog"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demo:

- Signature;

  > **`calc(operators, numbers)`**
- First parameter is an array of integers in the range of 0 to 3 for operators:

  > **0:** `+`, **1:** `-`, **2:** `*`, **3:** `/`
  >   ex. **[0, 1, 3, 3, 2]**  is `+`, `-`, `/`, `/`, `*`
- Second parameter is an array of floats to calculate.
- For optimal operation:

  - Second parameter length should be exactly one greater than the length of the first parameter

    > ex. `calc([1, 0, 3], [24, 88, 185, 11]) //11`
- Behavior for other than optimal input:

  - If the length of the length of the second parameter is 2 or more greater than the length of the first parameter, the second parameter length will be truncated so that it's length is one greater than the first parameter.

    > ex. `calc([1, 0, 3], [24, 88, 185, 11, 325]) //11`
  - If both parameters have equal length or the first parameter length is greater than the second parameter length, then the extra numbers in the first parameter are ignored.

    > ex. `calc([1, 0, 3, 2, 1], [24, 88, 185, 11]) //11`
  - If there's only one number in the second parameter or the first parameter has a number other than [0-3] that number is returned. This behavior is like how a calculator handles erroneous inputs.

    > ex. `calc([1, 0, 3], [11]) //11`

I made the first parameter an array of numbers because string can be messy, plus there should be 0% chance of any input being a non-number unless done intentionally. The chained ternary determines the operator on each iteration of `reduce()`. Instead of declaring the `initialValue`, the operators kick in on the second iteration so that a alternating pattern is processed:

> ```
> // First iteration: 
> numbers[0] // Accumulator
>  // Second iteration:
> operators[0], numbers[0] /* Accumulator */ numbers[1] // currentValue
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
/*
@Params
|-operators: Array of numbers | range [0-3] 
| 0: +, 1: -, 2: *, 3: /
|-numbers: Array of floats
| numbers.length = operators.length + 1
@Return
|-a float
*/
const calc = ([...opr], [...num]) => {
  return num.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
    if (num.length - opr.length !== 1) {
      num.length = opr.length + 1
    }
    if (idx > 0) {
      let op = opr[idx - 1];
      let exp = (op === 0) ? acc + cur : (op === 1) ? acc - cur : (op === 2) ? acc * cur : (op === 3) ? acc / cur : acc + 0;
      return exp;
    }
  });
}

console.log(calc([1], [1, 5, 22]));
console.log(calc([0, 1], [55, 2, 0.3]));
console.log(calc([2, 3], [22, 6]));
console.log(calc([3, 1, 2], [51, 3, 3, 5]));
console.log(calc([1, 0, 3], [24, 88, 185, 11]));
console.log(calc([0], [94]));
console.log(calc([5, 6, 1], [94, 22]));
```